# How to run a LOOCV test with missing values?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to run a LOOCV test this way:

```
reglin = glm(imdb_score~bs(movie_facebook_likes,knots=c(454.5,2000,19000), degree=1)+poly(duration,5)+bs(director_facebook_likes,knots=c(4,44,189.25), degree=1)+budget+poly(title_year,2)+genres+`sub genres`+`sub genres`*genres)
cv.error=cv.glm(life_hope_dataset_2, reglin)$delta[1]
cv.error
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor genres has new level Romance
```

as well as this:

```
In addition: Warning message:
In predict.lm(d.glm, data[j.out, , drop = FALSE], type = "response") :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading
```

I believe this is happening because I have missing values for some movies genres and sub genres but I am not sure... If this is the case, is there any way to still run the LOOCV test? Maybe I can create a data frame with only the rows that have no null values and run the test with this but I do not know how I could go with this.

I would be very thankful for any indication!

Comment: Does your data only one point with genre=Romance?

Comment: No it changes when I run it, I also had western for example ...